# Finding the restriction maps of the image presheaf using the universal property

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory

Let $\varphi:\mathscr{F}\to\mathscr{G}$ be a morphism of presheaves over a topological space $X$ with values in an abelian category $\sf{C}$. As usual, we define the image presheaf $\operatorname{im}\varphi$ as being $\operatorname{im}\varphi(U):=\operatorname{im}\varphi_U$, where $\operatorname{im}\varphi_U$ is the kernel of the cokernel of $\varphi_U$. Surely, since limits and colimits in functor categories are computed pointwise, that coincides with the kernel of the cokernel of $\varphi$.

I know the restriction maps of both the kernel and the cokernel presheaves, which defines the restriction maps of the image presheaf. Nevertheless, I think that maybe we could have a simpler description of those maps by using the universal property of the image.

Let $V\subset U$ be a pair of nested open sets in $X$ and consider the commutative diagram below.

[image]

I think that maybe we could use the universal property of $\operatorname{im}\varphi_V$ to obtain our map $\operatorname{im}\varphi_V\to\operatorname{im}\varphi_V$. For that, it suffices to find a monomorphism $\operatorname{im}\varphi_V\to \mathscr{G}(U)$ but I fail to see what that would be. I would appreciate if anyone knows how to define such a monomorphism or if anyone know a better way of constructing these restriction maps.

Just for being sure that we're on the same page, the universal property of the image says that the image of $\varphi:A\to B$ is a monomorphism $i:K\to B$ such that $\varphi$ factors through $i$ and that is initial with these properties. That is, if $L\to B$ is another monomorphism through which $\varphi$ also factors, then it exists a unique morphism $K\to L$ such that the diagram
[image]

commutes.

Comment: I'm probably disregarding a subtlety here, but $\text{im}$ is a functor, resulting as the composition of a certain colimit followed by a certain limit. Thus, it induces a restriction map at least over presheaves. Now, for sheaves... what happens to the sheaf condition?

Comment: @Fosco, indeed the restriction map is well defined. What I mean is that probably there's some natural way to think about those maps. For example, when $\sf{C}$ is an "algebraic" category, the image is naturally a subset of $\mathscr{G}(U)$ and then all that we need are the restriction maps of $\mathscr{G}$. This is way simpler than using two universal properties. Also, all that I'm doing here is in the category of presheaves but no new phenomena arise in the category of sheaves. In fact, the sheafification functor is left adjoint and so preserves colimits. [...]

Comment: [...] In particular, in order to construct a colimit of sheaves, we can construct the same colimit in the category of presheaves and then sheafify. In our case, this means that the sheafification of the presheaf image that we're talking here is not only a sheaf but also satisfies the universal property of images in the category of sheaves.